# I'm performing sentiment analysis on https://www.kaggle.com/snap/amazon-fine-food-reviews dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk, stop-words

I want create the wordcloud for the most frequently used words.

```
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
stopwords.update(["br", "href"])
textt = " ".join(review for review in df.Text)
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords).generate(textt)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig('wordcloud11.png')
plt.show()
```

I tried getting it using this code but I'm getting an error
NameError: name 'STOPWORDS' is not defined
Can please anybody help me out with this.

Comment: as the error suggests, `STOPWORDS` is never defined. the current code is incomplete. you need to define a `STOPWORDS` list before you can take its set. if you copied this block of code, `STOPWORDS` might have been defined somewhere before this code block.

Comment: it's also not clear to me why `stopwords` is imported and then immediately reassigned as something else.

Comment: No this is the only piece of code.

Comment: I tried it by changing stopword to STOPWORD and adding WordCloud . Still it shows same error.

Comment: original code did not have them defined. i didn't change them randomly, I just tried if that works.  I'm thankful for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `STOPWORDS` and `WordCloud`. You need to import or define them first. You can use the ones defined in `wordcloud` package by importing them. Here is the complete code you will need. I have removed `import nltk` statement since you are not using it. Also I assume you already have a `pandas` dataframe `df` defined with a `Text` field.

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
stopwords.update(["br", "href"])
textt = " ".join(review for review in df.Text)
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords).generate(textt)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig('wordcloud11.png')
plt.show()
```